# What is the difference between reactive dependencies and not a reactive dependencies in Vue componet?

Tags: vue.js

In [Vuejs guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods),

What is the difference between reactive dependencies and not a reactive dependencies ?

Answer (score 4):

The data and properties you use within a `computed` property function are its *dependencies*.

Reactive dependencies are those that are observable, like `data` properties or Vuex *state*.

Non-reactive dependencies would be something like a simple variable or something from local-storage. For example

```js
const someArray = [1, 2, 3]
export default {
  data: () => ({ foo: 'foo' }),
  computed: {
    FOO () {
      return this.foo.toUpperCase() // data property "foo" is a reactive dependency
    },
    firstArrayValue () {
      return someArray[0] // variable "someArray" is a non-reactive dependency
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can have a good night’ｓ sleep tonight.